# What is the Search/Prediction Time Complexity of Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, time-complexity, logistic-regression

I am looking into the time complexities of Machine Learning Algorithms and I cannot find what is the time complexity of Logistic Regression for predicting a new input. I have read that for Classification is O(c*d) c-beeing the number of classes, d-beeing the number of dimensions and I know that for the Linear Regression the search/prediction time complexity is O(d). Could you maybe explain what is the search/predict time complexity of Logistic Regression?
Thank you in advance

Example For The other Machine Learning Problems: 
https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine/learning/computational-complexity-learning-algorithms/

Comment: sorry it's my first question

Comment: Complexity is not defined for a *problem* (i.e. logistic regression), but for specific *algorithms* that solve a problem; see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-computational-complexity-of-a-classification-problem-Is-it-P-or-NP

Comment: @desertnaut this complexity is for training and not prediction

Comment: Fair point; so, for `k` features it is the complexity of multiplying `k` pairs of numbers (i.e. the model coefficients X the features) and then adding them, plus one more addition operation for the bias term (per sample), right? (Still, it is unclear what you mean by "search"...)

Comment: I have added an article which maybe will clarify what I need, so in this article they show the Training Time complexity  and the prediction/search time complexity meaning what is the complexity of predicting y for new point x.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Complexity of training for logistic regression methods with gradient based optimization: O((f+1)csE), where:

- **f** - number of features (+1 because of bias). Multiplication of each feature times it's weight (`f` operations, `+1` for bias). Another `f + 1` operations for summing all of them (obtaining prediction). Using gradient method to improve weights counts for the same number of operations, so in total we get **4* (f+1)** (two for forward pass, two for backward), which is simply **O(f+1)**.
- **c** - number of classes (possible outputs) in your logistic regression. For binary classification it's one, so this term cancels out. Each class has it's corresponding set of weights.
- **s** - number of samples in your dataset, this one is quite intuitive I think.
- **E** - number of epochs you are willing to run the gradient descent (whole passes through dataset)

**Note:** this complexity can change based on things like regularization (another c operations), but the idea standing behind it goes like this.

### Complexity of predictions for one sample: O((f+1)c)

- **f + 1** - you simply multiply each weight by the value of feature, add bias and sum all of it together in the end.
- **c** - you do it for every class, 1 for binary predictions.

### Complexity of predictions for many samples: O((f+1)cs)

- **(f+1)c** - see complexity for one sample
- **s** - number of samples

### Difference between logistic and linear regression in terms of complexity: activation function.

For multiclass logistic regression it will be **softmax**, while linear regression, as the name suggests, has linear activation (effectively no activation). It does not change the complexity using big O notation, but it's another **c*f** operations during the training (didn't want to clutter the picture further) multiplied by 2 for backprop.