# Train a logistic regression model in parts for big data

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, bigdata, logistic-regression

My data set consists of 1.6 million rows and 17000 columns after preprocessing. I want to use logistic regression on this data, however the process gets killed everytime I load the dataset. Is there a way I can train a logistic regression model in chunks, wit the coefficients being updated at each iteration. Does sklearn support any technique for my problem?

Comment: Which logistic regression algorithm are you using?

Comment: One option would be the `partial_fit` method of `SGDClassifier` for LR & SVM's; see [Is it possible to train a sklearn model (eg SVM) incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722861/is-it-possible-to-train-a-sklearn-model-eg-svm-incrementally/54723127#54723127)

Answer (score 1):

first, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238493/what-is-the-search-prediction-time-complexity-of-logistic-regression). the time to train a LR on your data set is.... a bit high.
to avoid that, you can use the warm start param of LR in sklearn and loop over chunck of your datas.

> warm_start : bool, default: False When set to True, reuse the solution
>   of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise, just erase
>   the previous solution. Useless for liblinear solver. See the Glossary.

(from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html))

and to be more precise:

> warm_start When fitting an estimator repeatedly on the same dataset,
>   but for multiple parameter values (such as to find the value
>   maximizing performance as in grid search), it may be possible to reuse
>   aspects of the model learnt from the previous parameter value, saving
>   time. When warm_start is true, **the existing fitted model attributes an
>   are used to initialise the new model in a subsequent call to fit**.

(from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-warm-start))

Comment: Links to the used quotes would be appropriate here

Comment: true. Updated to add the links